# Animate constraints and frame at the same time

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, segue

I want to override the `perform` method of an UIStoryboardSegue subclass.

Therefore I will have to animate constraints **and** frames of different objects using `UIView.animateWithDuration`.

Is it possible, to do such animations of constraints and frames in one `UIView.animateWithDuration` method?
Can you post an example?

Comment: You can do all the changes you want inside the block of that method and they will happen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use layoutIfNeeded() to animate constraint.

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()

constraintToAnimate.constant = 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```